# Trusted Certificate in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssl, sql-server-2012, database-administration

First of all I am not a Network Admin/DBA.I would like to know about the below.

In a Sql 2012 db all db traffic  to Sql server has to be **encrypted** by using secure socket layer(SSL) certificate.What exactly are these  trusted SSL certificate?Is it something to do in in OS level? or in  SQL SERVER .Where /How to implement these certificate?

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know why did some fools marking negative for the question.I can understand,if they mention some comments.With out mentioning the comments and giving negative is really irritating.Who ever marking negative,without a comment is definitely an idiot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be a jerk about it, but I literally threw "SQL SSL" into Google and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898) was the first result.